# Стартовая страница при подключении по wifi

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, hotspot

Помогите советом плз, может кто сталкивался с такой задачей.

Настроен hot spot на ubuntu mate 20.4
Подключаясь по wifi и вбивая адрес 10.42.0.1 попадаю на стартовую страницу.
Нужно, что бы при подключении к wifi стартовая страница открывалась автоматически (без роутера). В инете в основном решения через настройку роутеров. В моём случае такое решение не подходит. Хочу подключаться на прямую к конкретному компьютеру.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Captive Portal это называется. Как без подсовывания своего роутера / прокси / DNS результата вы не получите

Comment: Спасибо. Буду копать.